# mod_authz_host is ignored

Tags: mod-auth

I'm having problems with one of my servers (Centos 6.3 using Apache 2.2.25). The mod_authz_host seems to be ignored even though it is enabled in the httpd.conf

I have almost all the modules enabled by default but even if I do something like:

```
<Directory "/"> 
Order deny,allow
deny from all
</Directory>
```

I still can access to every page.  Even the default protection against reading the .htaccess is ignored.

This is the list of modules that are currently loaded:

- LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
- LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
- LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
- LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
- LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
- LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
- LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
- LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
- LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
- LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
- LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
- LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
- LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
- #LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
- #LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
- LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
- LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
- LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
- LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
- LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
- LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
- LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
- LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
- LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
- LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
- LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
- LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
- LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
- LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
- LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
- LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
- LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
- LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
- LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
- LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
- LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
- LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
- LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
- LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
- LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
- #LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
- #LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
- #LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
- #LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
- #LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
- LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
- #LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
- LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
- LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so

What am I doing wrong? :-(